# How to optimize inputs for an ode system using fmincon

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, nonlinear-optimization

Hello please I am new to using fmincon for optimization, I want to optimize a dynamic system model of ODEs. I have solved the system using Euler explicit with a static input but now I want to perform an optimization for the best input that will maximize the objective function. Please how do I go about implementing the ODEs as my constraints. I have read that I will dvelop 3 scripts; 1st the objective function, 2nd for the nonlcon, and 3rd the call script but I don't know how to use the ODE as my constraint in the script. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The use of fmincon is extensively documented by MathWorks. Either use this [link](https://in.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) or type `doc fmincon` in the MATLAB editor.